# Behaviour of Stream when the source of the Stream is changed after the Stream is created

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Consider this code below :

```
     List<Integer> l=new ArrayList<>();
     l.add(23);l.add(45);l.add(90);

     Stream<Integer> str=l.stream();     // mark A

     l.add(111);
     l=null;

     System.out.println(str.collect(Collectors.toList())); // mark B
```

OUTPUT IS :

```
[23, 45, 90, 111]
```

I am assuming here that when terminal operation is called at mark B then RHS of mark A is evaluated
which means recent list (with element "111") is getting picked but the question is why we aren't getting
`NullPointerException` here.. if we aren't getting the exception then we shouldn't be getting the "111"
in the output as well.. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`l.stream()` creates a `Stream` that probably keeps a reference to the source `List` (I'm saying probably because that's an implementation detail).

At the time you consume the `Stream`, the `List` already has 4 elements, so 4 elements are consumed.

Changing the `l` reference to `null` doesn't affect the reference stored within the `Stream` instance.

> if we aren't getting the excpetion then we shouldn't be getting the "111" in the output as well.

That would be true only if the `Stream` implementation created a copy of the source `List` instead of just keeping a reference to the original `List`. Since that would be wasteful in terms of memory usage, it's not surprising that this is not the behavior.

Looking at the implementation of `Collection`'s `stream()` (at least in Java 8), I see:

```
default Stream<E> stream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
}
```

`spliterator()` is overridden by `ArrayList`:

```
public Spliterator<E> spliterator() {
    return new ArrayListSpliterator<>(this, 0, -1, 0);
}
```

and `ArrayListSpliterator` keeps a reference to the source `List`, as anticipated:

```
static final class ArrayListSpliterator<E> implements Spliterator<E> {
    ....
    private final ArrayList<E> list;
    private int index; // current index, modified on advance/split
    private int fence; // -1 until used; then one past last index
    private int expectedModCount; // initialized when fence set

    /** Create new spliterator covering the given  range */
    ArrayListSpliterator(ArrayList<E> list, int origin, int fence,
                         int expectedModCount) {
        this.list = list; // OK if null unless traversed
        this.index = origin;
        this.fence = fence;
        this.expectedModCount = expectedModCount;
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Note that [this is not just an implementation detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58096130/2711488)

Answer (score 5):

This behavior is explicitly stated in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference):

> For well-behaved stream sources, the source can be modified before the
>    terminal operation commences and those modifications will be reflected in
>    the covered elements.  For example, consider the following code:
>
> ```
> List<String> l = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("one", "two"));
> Stream<String> sl = l.stream();
> l.add("three");
> String s = sl.collect(joining(" "));
> ```
>
> First a list is created consisting of two strings: "one"; and "two". Then a
>    stream is created from that list. Next the list is modified by adding a third
>    string: "three". Finally the elements of the stream are collected and joined
>    together. Since the list was modified before the terminal `collect`
>    operation commenced the result will be a string of "one two three". All the
>    streams returned from JDK collections, and most other JDK classes,
>    are well-behaved in this manner; for streams generated by other libraries, see
>    [Low-level stream construction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamSources) for requirements for building well-behaved streams.